# How to create canvas that scales well with browser window resize

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, responsive

I can't seem to get my canvas to be perfectly responsive.
Using 100% or 100vmax for height and width makes it responsive but it looses clarity.

The center of the canvas seems to be at the bottom of the page as if the canvas stretches beyond the screen

[canvas when width is set to 100% or 100vmax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoRYx.jpg)

[Canvas when width is set through javaScript NOT RESPONSIVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaUEP.jpg)

Comment: Hi, your request is unclear, can you explain better what's the desired behaviour?

Comment: If you look in the image where the width and height is set to 100vmax the dots look stretched. That's my problem. It's perfectly responsive with window sizing but the dots are stretched even when the window is small

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to know the aspect ratio of the `canvas` to do this. You can't simply apply 100% width and height as that will stretch to 100% width and 100% height of the body.

**Example:**

Lets say I have a `Canvas` with the dimensions of `864 x 576` and I want it to be responsive to the full body.

Find the percentage/ratio of the `canvas`. To do this you can do it manually or through JavaScript. In this example lets do it manually for a non-changing image.

**ratio = width / height * 100**

So here our ratio will be `ratio = 864 / 576 * 100` that would be 150% (as in 1.5:1 or 3:2)

We now add the styles using the viewport height `vh`.

```
canvas
{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Now one problem remains. What if the window width is smaller than the canvas? Okay, we create a CSS media query and do the opposite of what we've done.

**ratio = (height / width) * 100**

So here our ratio will now be `ratio = 576 / 864 * 100` that would be 66.66% (as in 0.66:1 or 7:10)

We need to use the viewport width now for the `canvas` width and height. width is always `100vh`.

```
@media (max-width: 150vh)
{
  canvas
  {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 66.66vw;
  }
}
```

The `max-width` media query needs to be equal to the canvas width, which is 150vh in this example.

Take a look at the code: https://codepen.io/StudioKonKon/pen/oQobaa

```js
var image = "https://res.cloudinary.com/studiokonkon/image/upload/v1541450918/sample.jpg";

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 864;
canvas.height = 576;


var background = new Image();
background.src = image;

// Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
background.onload = function()
{
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);   
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #000; }

.mycanvas
{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media (max-width: 150vh)
{
  .mycanvas
  {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 66.66vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Please be aware support of the vh and vw units are only supported in the latest browsers and assuming you don't care about Internet Explorer.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units